# How to import a Django app from Git into a project

Tags: django, git

I want to include a Django app into the project I'm working on. The app is hosted on Github ( https://github.com/lmorchard/django-badger ). As well as the app's directory containing the goodies, there are some files in the root - README, LICENCE, TODO and setup.py. If I clone the app into my project's root directory, the app folder will be in the correct place, but those root files will be in my project's root. How can I add the app while still tracking the upstream code in Github?

Comment: pip install django-badger did not work?

Comment: @karthikr: Hadn't actually thought of that - I might be forking django-badger so I was thinking of pulling straight from git, but maybe I'll cross that bridge when I come to it

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where I was working on two independent projects where both were in a repo, and one of them used the other as an app:

- Create a virtualenv and install all dependencies for both projects. I usually like to have a virtualenv for each project/repo but in this case you need one env which can execute Python from both repos.
- Clone both repos to independent location. Do not clone the depending app inside the other project. Your file-structure then might look like this (assuming Django 1.3 project layout):

  ```
  project/
    manage.py
    project/
      __init__.py
      settings.py
      ...
    ...

  app/
    README
    ...
    app/
      __init__.py
      models.py
      ...
  ```
- And final step is to create a symlink (or shortcut on Windows) from the app directory which has `__init__.py` in it to the project path.

  ```
  $ ln -s /abs/path/to/app/app /abs/path/to/project/
  ```
- Now you can use the virtualenv to run the project!

The final result is that you have two independent repos however one of projects is using the other project without directly copying the code, hence allowing you to maintain two repos.

Answer (score 1):

U can install it by running

```
python setup.py
```

or through pip

```
sudo pip install -e git+https://github.com/lmorchard/django-badger#egg=django-badger
```

Comment: `pip install -e git+https://github.com/lmorchard/django-badger#egg=django-badger` is throwing an error.

Comment: iam sorry i think you need to use sudo. updating accordingly

Comment: I have tried it. I used `sudo pip install -e git+https://github.com/lmorchard/django-badger#egg=django-badger`. But it is throwing an error.

Comment: @arulmr: People cannot help you if you don't tell them anything about your problem. What does the error say?

Comment: This command works fine now. There was a problem in the older version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository from github using `git://github.com/lmorchard/django-badger.git`. Then open the cloned folder in terminal. Install the app using the command `sudo python setup.py install`. This will work good. If you want to have the app included in your project, create a folder named **badger**(or anything you wish) and copy the installed app from dist-packages to created folder.